# how to calculate expiration date VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
 Dim readers As MySqlDataReader

    cn.Open()
    Dim query As String
    query = "Select * from tblmeds where expdate='" & DateTime.Now & "'"
    command = New MySqlCommand(query, cn)
    readers = command.ExecuteReader

    Dim count As Integer
    count = 0
    While readers.Read
       count = count + 1
    End While

        cn.Close()

        If count = 0 Then

           MsgBox("no expiration")
        Else
            MsgBox("medicine at risk")
        End If
```

this is just the code i made but it doesnt work because it doesnt go to while instead is goes straight for if count=0. also how can i say to my program "if the expiration date on the database is near month i set to" sorry for my bad english

Comment: DateTime.Now contains also hour, minutes and seconds. You are checking if any of your items has exactly this value. Do you instead want to use <= ?

Comment: hmm on my database i only have exact date for expiration date no time. how can i check ONLY date? what should i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a timestamp difference:

```
query = "Select * from tblmeds where TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,`expdate`,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())< 1"
```

Comment: jesus christ it works omg THANK YOU!! btw i need your help again

Answer (score 2):

You are checking if any of your items has an expiry date exactly equals to the current value of DateTime.Now. This property contains also the Time part and thus it is highly improbable that you have an item with exactly the same value.

I think you would use instead 'expdate lesser than now' thus your code should be

```
Dim readers As MySqlDataReader
cn.Open()
Dim query As String
query = "Select * from tblmeds where expdate<=@exp"
command = New MySqlCommand(query, cn)
command.Parameters.Add("@exp", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
readers = command.ExecuteReader
Dim count As Integer
count = 0
While readers.Read
   count = count + 1
End While
cn.Close()
If count = 0 Then
    MsgBox("no expiration")
Else
    MsgBox("medicine at risk")
End If
```

Instead if you want to check for expiry date equals to today date then the expression to use is `DateTime.Today` instead of DateTime.Now.

Notice also that is a very good practice to never concatenate strings to form sql queries. Use always a parameter approach to avoid parsing and conversion errors.

Comment: ^1 for avoiding SQL injection attack with query parameters.